# Kodi update for complete novice

Tags: kodi

Last year I got a raspberry pi 2 with (OSMC ) Kodi already installed on it. I want to upgrade the kodi version as simply as possible. Any help ?

Comment: Do you have auto-update enabled in the settings menu? On the same page you can check for updates. Kodi is the latest version of XBMC I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I can see a couple of options on the [osmc.tv/wiki](https://osmc.tv/wiki/) page:

[Setting up an update schedule](https://osmc.tv/wiki/general/keeping-your-osmc-system-up-to-date/)

> By default, OSMC will check for updates automatically and prompt you.
>   You can refine this via My OSMC. If you are using the default OSMC
>   skin, then My OSMC will be accessible via your Home screen. If you are
>   using Confluence then it will be available via the Settings sub-menu.
>   For other skins, My OSMC can be found via the Programs section.
>
> To change the update schedule, select Updater. You will now be able to
>   configure OSMC's update behaviour.
>
> Did you know?: you can also force an update check on demand by going
>   to My OSMC -> Updater -> Manual Controls -> Check for updates now.

[Manual update](https://osmc.tv/2015/07/osmc-updates-explained)

> We recommend users use the OSMC Updater via Kodi, but running:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```
>
> will keep your system up to date and will not cause any issues.

Answer (score -1):

check the link below

http://mymediaexperience.com/xbmc-guide/

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.